# Upload a file from java client to a apache http server

Tags: java, apache, http

I'm trying to upload a "myfile.txt" file into the apache server(WAMP) as "uploaded.txt" using apache HttpClient api but i'm getting "404 not found" status.

```
public class Httpupload1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        String url = "http://username:password@localhost/uploaded.txt";

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        ContentBody body = new FileBody(
                new File("C:/Users/username/Desktop/myfile.txt"),
                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM
                );

        entity.addPart("file", body);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());


    }
}
```

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that the URL you show is related to anything that would accept and process a file upload.

Comment: @BrianRoach can u pls tell me how to send the request? its not working even if there is no username:password.

Comment: As @BrianRoach said, I think there is noting on the server side (PHP code, ...) accepting the upload. You only have the client side here. WAMP does not do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the DefaultHttpClient nor the AndroidHttpClient digest URLs like user:password@...
Instead you need to use B64 encoding in order to transmit your credentials to the apache server.

To do so try this

```
     public String getB64Auth (String login, String pass) {
       String source=login+":"+pass;
       String auth="Basic "+android.util.Base64.encodeToString(source.getBytes(),android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
       return auth;
     }
```

The resulting string then has to be added to your HttpPost object

```
String auth = getB64Auth("username","password");
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
postRequest.addHeader("Authorization",auth);
```

Also you need something (like a php script) that accepts the data on the server side. I doubt that "uploaded.txt" does that... 
This script is also responsible for processing, naming and saving the received file. For example you could use a StringBody you add to your MultiPartEntity to pass the name to be used to save the file on the server side.

See http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp for more information

Comment: I don't have a php script. I just need to copy some files from client side into the server.